# svn tags keep getting modified during merges

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, tree-conflict

I am running an `svn` client on Windows 7. I use TortoiseSVN, but rely mostly on the command line client.

I made my own branch `cr0` from the `trunk` and made some local changes to the files there. When I merged these files back to the `trunk` using the command

`svn merge -r2000:3000 local\path1\cr0 local\path2\trunk`

as expected, the `trunk` obtained the correct files.

Now I am trying to merge some other changes (which did not touch my files) back into `cr0` using

`svn merge -r2000:4000 local\path2\trunk local\path1\cr0`

the same files that were changed on the original merge now change tags in `cr0` - why does this happen and how do I get rid of it?

I tried accepting the changes, and trying immediately to merge back to `trunk`, and the ones in the `trunk` now change tags as well. This happens on every merge either from `cr0` to `trunk` or vice versa. There is plenty of files, where this does *not* happen (which I think should be the expected behavior).

How do I stop these files from changing tags every merge? Thank you very much

Comment: Have you looked at *what* has changed? Is it file contents, or just properties?

Comment: @alroc yes, like i wrote in the question, it is just the properties, not the file itself.

Comment: You never specified that it was only properties. Merging always creates an `svn:mergeinfo` property even if nothing has changed so that it has a record of all merges that were performed.

Comment: @alroc that `svn:mergeinfo` (in later versions of svn) marks the top of the merge tree, not individual files